# Do two altitudes uniquely determine the third

Tags: geometry, contest-math

BdMO 2014 Nationals

> If the lengths of two altitudes drawn from two vertices of a triangle on their opposite sides are $2014$
>   and $1$ unit, then what will be the length of the altitude drawn from the third vertex of the triangle on its 
>   opposite side?

Obviously,we can look at the specific case where the triangle is a right triangle,then use similar triangles and Pythagoras.The problem is implying that the third height,no matter what we do,stays constant.If so ,how do we prove it?I have,by chasing similar triangles,managed to prove that one of the sides is $2014$ times the other,but I don't find it intuitive that the third height will be unique.Hence,my question comes in two parts:

1)How do we answer the question as presented?

2)Do two altitudes uniquely determine the third?If so,why?

Comment: If two altitudes uniquely determine the third, then it determines the triangle, which I think should not be possible though...

Comment: @Sawarnik,true,it seems.So the problem is unanswerable as currently posed.

Comment: By the triangle inequality, the length of the third altitude $h$ must satisfy $\frac{2014}{2015} < h < \frac{2014}{2013}$.

Comment: @rah4927 Yes, it is. But how could such a problem come up in your nationals?

Comment: @Sawarnik,no idea.They probably corrected it after the exam had started,but didn't mention it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K$ be the area of the triangle, let $a,b,c$ be the sides with altitudes of $2014,1,h$ respectively.

Then, $K = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot a \cdot 2014 = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot b \cdot 1 = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot c \cdot h$, so $a = \dfrac{2K}{2014}$, $b = 2K$, and $c = \dfrac{2K}{h}$.

Thus, this triangle has a semiperimeter of $s = \dfrac{1}{2}(a+b+c) = K\left(\dfrac{1}{h}+\dfrac{2015}{2014}\right)$.

So, the area satisfies $K^2 = s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$

$= K\left(\dfrac{1}{h}+\dfrac{2015}{2014}\right) \cdot K\left(\dfrac{1}{h}+\dfrac{2013}{2014}\right) \cdot K\left(\dfrac{1}{h}-\dfrac{2013}{2014}\right) \cdot K\left(-\dfrac{1}{h}+\dfrac{2015}{2014}\right)$

$= K^4\left(\dfrac{1}{h^2}-\dfrac{2013^2}{2014^2}\right)\left(\dfrac{2015^2}{2014^2}-\dfrac{1}{h^2}\right)$.

So for any $h$ such that $\dfrac{2014}{2015} < h < \dfrac{2014}{2013}$, let $K = \left[\left(\dfrac{1}{h^2}-\dfrac{2013^2}{2014^2}\right)\left(\dfrac{2015^2}{2014^2}-\dfrac{1}{h^2}\right)\right]^{-1/2}$,

and let $a = \dfrac{2K}{2014}$, $b = 2K$, and $c = \dfrac{2K}{h}$. This will give us the sidelengths $a,b,c$ of a triangle with altitudes $2014,1,h$ respectively. Clearly, two altitudes do not uniquely determine the third. However, if one of the two altitudes is very long, we get good bounds on the third altitude's length

Now if by some chance you were told that the third altitude $h$ was an integer, then the only possible value would be $h = 1$. But if that is the case, the problem should have specified that.